# How to put a third party library into the local repository if it is not publicly downloadable?

Tags: java, maven-2, maven

Some 3rd party JAR files are not found in the public maven repository. To use them, do I need to manully add them to the local repository? Any steps to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define a minimal pom for each jar and install them into the local repository. There's even [a guide](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html) for it.

The command (copied and pasted from the guide) is:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id> \
    -DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=<packaging>
```

Comment: groupId could be com.example.project and artifact id library-name: If we have jar aspectj-maven-plugin.jar from codehauses mojo, then you'd use org.codehaus.mojo as groupId and aspectj-maven-plugin as artifactId

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the answer of Aleksi you can also introduce a maven proxy, like [Nexus](http://nexus.sonatype.org/) or [artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/products.php).

These tools are accessed by maven (if so configured) to get the artifacts, and they in turn download them when required. With such a tool in place your local maven need only know about a single location, and the Nexus or Artifactory can map a series of internet repositories to a single "virtual" one. You can of course upload your own artifacts too.

If you're developing on your own with a fast internet connection it might be a bit overkill though.

If you're in an enterprise setting I'd recommend Artifactory. Nexus is not always tested all that well with older Maven versions :(